# ASK CLI hangs when creating a new Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am struggling a bit with the ask client. I properly configured it, but when I create a new skill, the client hangs with "Creating your Alexa hosted skill. It will take about a minute.".

The skill is created and I can see it in the developer console in Amazon, but locally I do not get any initial setup. Is there a way to debug what is failing in the process?

Answer (score 0):

You may get some relevant information from the command `ask new --debug` when creating a new skill. Additionally, you can check the new skill page in the developer console for any errors or warnings.

For example, I reproduced this behavior by trying to create a new skill named 'ask skill test'. The skill failed to build, and the developer console showed the error "Invocation name must not contain launch word."